# Выше написанный / вышенаписанный

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Каждое из вышенаписанных / выше написанных предложений имееет орфоошибку.`

`Каждое из предложений, вышенаписанных / выше написанных, имееет орфоошибку.`

Comment: Если слова нет в словарях, о правильности нет смысла рассуждать.

Comment: Нет, стоит.  Эта тема не так проста, как можно подумать. Контроль по словарю нужен, но и понимание того, как образуются подобные слова, тоже необходимо.  Это термины, которые к тому легко переходят в словосочетания.  Голос от меня.

Comment: Минус за "орфоошибка" - слово составленное не верно, так как: корни должны быть греческие, кроме того орфо и ошибка, даже если не следовать сказанному в начале, не сочетаются никак, слитное написание не возможно. Насчёт "вышенаписанных" - написанных выше, либо вышеупомянутых. Вышенаписанный - некорректно по ряду причин. Пример не корректный.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Каждое из **выше написанных** предложений имеет орфографическую ошибку.* *Каждое из предложений, **написанных выше,** имеет орфографическую ошибку.*

**Пояснение**

(1) Подобные слова являются **терминами**, но многие из них имеют парные словосочетания с раздельным написанием.

(2) Нет слова ***вышенаписанный***. Причастия не как часто используются для образования терминов, как прилагательные. Нужен контроль **по словарю**.

Сравнить:

**ВЫШЕСКАЗАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Книжн. Сказанный, изложенный выше, раньше. <Вышесказанное, -ого; ср. Всё в-ое подтверждает этот вывод.

Наиболее **приемлемый вариант:** [https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/вышеприведённый](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

*В-пятых, философия, как мы увидели с помощью **вышеприведённого** примера, помогает человеку быть счастливым.*

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (краткая теория)

**Отличительные признаки термина**

Отличить термин от свободного словосочетания можно по **следующим признакам**: 1) по смысловым оттенкам, 2) по стилям, 3) с точки зрения произношения, по количеству ударений:  если словосочетание переходит в термин, то оно произносится с одним ударением.

**Слитно:** быстротекущее время   – термин (книжный стиль, обобщенное понятие). **Раздельно:**  быстро текущий ручей  – словосочетание (нейтральный стиль, конкретное понятие).

*Для меня  творчество –  попытка удержать что-то из течения **быстротекущего** времени.  В **быстро текущих** шумных ручьях звуки почти не слышны.*

**Влияние зависимых слов**

Под влиянием зависимых слов термин может перейти в исходное словосочетание с раздельным написанием:
**Слитно:** малознакомые места  глубокоуважаемый человек  – сложные слова со значением терминов.  **Раздельно**: мало знакомые нам места, глубоко уважаемый всеми человек – словосочетания при наличии зависимых слов.

*Участники игры попадут в хорошо известные или **малознакомые** исторические места.  Выезд проходил в безлюдные и **мало знакомые** для нас места.*

**Парные варианты (термины и словосочетания)**

В большинстве случаев **наречия**, входящие в состав **термина** со слитным написанием, могут входить и в состав **словосочетания**, где они всегда пишутся только  раздельно и при отсутствии зависимых слов:

**Слитно:** маловероятный исход, вечнозеленый кустарник – термины. **Раздельно:** мало изученный предмет, вечно молодой город – словосочетания наречия с прилагательными.

Сбой техники – **маловероятна**я причина аварии самолета. Самшит – **вечнозеленый** кустарник. Человек переходит на новый,  *мало изученный* уровень своих возможностей.  Мой город **вечно  молодой**.

**Только раздельное написание словосочетаний, похожих на термины**

Ряд словосочетаний, по структуре напоминающих термины, в действительности таковыми не являются  и всегда пишутся **раздельно** (они произносятся с двумя ударениями и паузой между словами):

**Раздельно:** трезво  мыслящий человек, жизненно важные проблемы – словосочетания.  Требуется контроль по словарю.

*Он добродушный и **трезво мыслящий** человек.  Дыхание – магическое, **жизненно важное** действие.*

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: https://kak-pravilno.net/vyshenapisannoe-ili-vyshe-napisannoe-kak-pravilno/

Comment: Разочарован вами!

Comment: And I tried so hard to charm you...  I use the dictionary of the Russian Academy of Sciences, sir, and I strongly advise you.

Comment: Еще вариант: приведите примеры из литературы. А то мне вот что предлагают https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/вышеуказанный   https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/вышесказанный  А "вышенаписанного" никак нет-с.

Comment: But, as the Ngram Viewer says, they write *вышенаписанный* more often! If the dictionary doesn't recognize it, why not write it like similar words, for example, *вышесказанный, вышеупомянутый*, etc.?

Comment: The Russian Academy of Sciences does not allow it, and this resource is the law for everyone. You don't want to break the law, do you?

Comment: Where is the note that says, "Надо писать 'выше написанный'"?

Comment: Так это словосочетание, сэр. А  РАН – это словарь для слов.

Comment: That dictionary simply hasn't got that word yet. There's nothing saying that *вышенаписанный* is incorrect, and this version is written oftener.

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=вышенаписанный&all=x

Comment: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/slitno-napisanie-slozhnyh-prilagatelnyh

Comment: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2550761-vyshenapisannyj-ili-vyshe-napisannyj-kak-pravilno-pochemu.html

Comment: Хорошо, сэр, я всё уже сказала, а с Большим  вопросом, я полагаю, вы сами разберетесь, сэр.  Эти люди, вероятно, не слышали никогда про словарь РАН.