# Подкорректируйте предложение, ниже написанное / предложение ниженаписанное

Tags: орфография

Я знаю, что надо писать так:

> Подкорректируйте ниженаписанное предложение.

А если инверция?

> Подкорректируйте предложение, ниже написанное / предложение ниженаписанное.

Comment: Снимаю минус, обсуждаемый вопрос!  Выражает стремление разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

*Подкорректируйте предложение, ниже написанное* — причастие с наречием в сравнительной степени, причастный оборот обособляем;

*Подкорректируйте предложение ниженаписанное* — сложное прилагательное;

*Подкорректируйте предложЕние, ниженапИсанное* — пауза перед прилагательным; оно является доп. информацией; смысловое выделение прилагательного (или для пояснения).

Опять-таки, все зависит от решения автора.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150164/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Правильная запись:

*Подкорректируйте предложение, **написанное ниже**.*

Или:

*Подкорректируйте предложение, **которое написано ниже**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Такая запись точно передает **смысл** сказанного и соответствует **стилю речи** в учебных текстах.
2. Термина "ниженаписанный" нет в словаре, использовать его нельзя.  **НАРУШЕНИЕ ПРАВИЛ!**
3. **Термины** — это особая тема. Для их правильного употребления **нужны основания.** В данном случае таких оснований нет. Поэтому нет оснований и для нарушения правил письма: **в пределах нормы** можно подобрать походящую структуру предложения.
4. Ряд словосочетаний, по структуре напоминающих термины, в действительности таковыми **не являются** и всегда пишутся **РАЗДЕЛЬНО** (они произносятся с двумя ударениями и паузой между словами).

**[Разбор темы на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475719/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/475721#475721)**

Answer (score 1):

Вчера на форуме был **неудачный день**: интонация  никому  не нужна, словарь РАН не указ, а грамматику здесь  предпочитают примерно-определительную.

А сегодня у меня в гостях **Вовка из Тридевятого царства**, слышали, наверное? Да-да,  это он,  автор знаменитой фразы: **«И так сойдет!»**  Обсуждаем с ним **словарь РАН.**

— *Я знаю, что надо писать так: «Подкорректируйте **ниженаписанное** предложение».*
— Тебе нравится это **высказывание**?
— Вполне на уровне. А что мешает писать  **слитно**?
— **В словаре РАН** такого слова нет.
— А там разве **все слова есть**? Вот слово «***метростанция***»,  его там тоже нет.
— Это **по правилам** можно написать,  чистое сложение двух существительных (метро + станция) или  сложное сокращение: станция метрополитена  — метростанция.
— Так и здесь **правила есть.**
— Здесь **термин**, а не все слова могут быть терминами.  Нельзя же придумывать слова и называть их терминами.
— Почему нельзя?  Например:   ***нижепоставленная** книга.*
— Все так и делают, поэтому термины нужно **обязательно** заносить в словарь.  Там приведено **много слов с НИЖЕ**-,  а этого слова нет.
— Может, оно носит **разговорный** характер.
— Какой разговорный характер, это же **термин**. Вот в словаре есть термин ***вышеописанный***,  но его используют как  ссылку на **фрагмент текста.**  А кому нужна эта ссылка на одно предложение!  Слово ***ниженаписанный***  даже звучит **СТРАННО!** Вот еще мнение из Большого Вопроса: *Слово "вышенаписанный" как-то **режет слух,** в отличие от общепринятых "вышеназванный", "вышеописанный".*
— Возможно, его пока не включили в словарь, так как оно испытывает **колебания.**
— **В Интернете да**, испытывает, вот **[обсуждение](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2550761-vyshenapisannyj-ili-vyshe-napisannyj-kak-pravilno-pochemu.html).**  А в **Нацкорпусе** нет ни одного примера, как и в Карте слов. И вот заключение по теме: **[НАРОДНАЯ ОРФОГРАФИЯ](http://live.mephist.ru/show/spelling/id/63760) !**  Скорее всего, вы написали это слово **правильно. Но это неточно**))
— Вот именно что народная, потому что  народу нравится. ***Нижеописанный*** или ***ниженаписанный*** — какая разница-то?  **И так сойдет!**
— Да уж,  твое ***И ТАК СОЙДЕТ*** даже в процентах обозначили:  **верно более чем на 65%.**

[image: И так сойдет]